# Unable to filter in power bi dax query

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, data-cleaning

I have 3 tables - AWS,Troux and Url-shortener. Troux to Url-shortener has 1 to many relationship. Troux to AWS has 1 to many relationship. They all have UUID as common column. UUID is a text column, value is alphanumeric. I need to select the 1st value of UUID column from Url-shortener and get the same UUID from Troux table so that I can get the cost from AWS table for that UUID.

```
Coversion = 
VAR FirstUUID = FIRSTNONBLANK('Url-shortener'[UUID], 1)
VAR FilteredTroux = FILTER(Troux, Troux[UUID] = FirstUUID)

SUMMARIZE( FILTER(
        AWS,
        AWS[UUID] = FilteredTroux[UUID]
    )
      , AWS[UUID] 
      , Troux[Application] 
      , "Cost", AWS[AWS Cost] 
      )
```

But `FilteredTroux[UUID]` here UUID is showing error as "cannot find UUID". But if we write `RETURN FilteredTroux` then it showing the all columns including UUID. Please help.

I am expecting the same value of UUID as an output from Troux table which I collect from Url-shortener table. Using DAX.

Comment: Is this a measure, calculated column or calculated table you are creating?

Comment: I want to create a new table.

Comment: A table with a single column?

Comment: see if I write RETURN FilteredTroux then it showing the all columns including UUID. But I want to get the UUID only. Yes  a single column table.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
Coversion = 
VAR FirstUUID = FIRSTNONBLANK('Url-shortener'[UUID], 1)
VAR FilteredTroux = FILTER(Troux, Troux[UUID] = FirstUUID)
RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS(FilteredTroux, "Column", [UUID])
```

Comment: this works. But my requirement is slightly different. I want to user the value of 'FilteredTroux[UUID]" to some other lines of code after that. 

what I am trying to say is like 

var UUID = FilteredTroux[UUID]
RETURN SUMMARIZE( FILTER(
        AWS,
        AWS[UUID] = uuid  -- AWS is a different table.
    )
      ,'Calendar'[Date]  --Calendar is a different table
      , AWS[UUID] 
      , Troux[Troux Application] 
      , "Cost", AWS[AWS Cost] 
      )

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your requirements. Try providing some sample data for each of your tables and your expected results.

Comment: Something like below -

Cost per application per day = 

VAR FirstUUID = FIRSTNONBLANK('url-shortener-report-generation-table'[application trouxid], 1)
VAR FilteredTroux = FILTER(Troux, Troux[Troux UUID] = FirstUUID)
VAR SelectedColumns = SELECTCOLUMNS(FilteredTroux, "Column", [Troux UUID])

RETURN SUMMARIZE( FILTER(
        AWS,
        AWS[Troux UUID] = SelectedColumns
    )
      ,'Calendar'[Date] 
      , AWS[Troux UUID] 
      , Troux[Troux Application] 
      , "Cost", AWS[AWS Cost] 
      )

Comment: `Cost per application per day = 
VAR FirstUUID = FIRSTNONBLANK('url-shortener-report-generation-table'[application trouxid], 1)
VAR FilteredTroux = FILTER(Troux, Troux[Troux UUID] = FirstUUID)
VAR SelectedColumns = SELECTCOLUMNS(FilteredTroux, "Column", [Troux UUID])
VAR SummaryTable = SUMMARIZE(
    FILTER(
        AWS,
        AWS[Troux UUID] IN SelectedColumns
    ),
    'Calendar'[Date],
    "Cost", AWS[AWS Cost]
)
RETURN SummaryTable

`
@davidebacci

Comment: did you get that?

Comment: You need to update your question with sample data for all the tables involved in your calculation along with your expected results otherwise it isn't clear what the requirement is.

Comment: Let me give u a brief -
I have 3 tables Troux, AWS, Url-shortener. Aws to Troux many to 1 relation. Troux to Url-shortener 1 to many relation. All of them having common column name as UUID.

I need to select 1st value from UUID column from Url-shortener table. `
Then I get the same value from Troux table.
by using UUID from FilteredTroux, I want to get the some other info from AWS table 

`SUMMARIZE( FILTER(
        AWS,
        AWS[UUID] = FilteredTroux  -- here I am seeing error
    )
      , AWS[UUID] 
      , Troux[Application Name] 
      , "Cost", AWS[AWS Cost] 
      )`

Comment: Can you upload a sample .pbix and share a link? Update your question with the additional requirements as the comments don't show everything clearly.

Comment: .pbix file using DirectQuery. Will be a problem to share. let me update the question.